# systemd socket activation listener end-of-program behaviour

Tags: systemd

What is the correct behavior on close of a systemd `AF_UNIX` socket activated daemon.

`daemon.socket` service file creates the socket, passes it to my daemon, which `accept()`s new connections. What is supposed to happen when my daemon ends?
The usual is to `close()` and `unlink()` the socket. However, that does what it says, and the UNIX socket is no longer available in the FS, even though daemon.socket is still reporting as activated, basically disabling socket re-activation.

How to create a systemd socket restart-able daemon that `listen()`s on its socket? Is the correct approach to leave the socket open?

Answer (score 0):

After experimentation and reading of relevant manpages and [cups](https://www.cups.org/) code, here is what I know:

There are two modes of functioning :

- `inetd` mode, where systemd `accept()`s the connection and passes the accepted FD to a newly spawned subprocess. This method is used by default by ssh.socket, whereby every connection spawns a new ssh process.
- Non-accepting mode, where the bound socket itself is forwarded to the daemon, which then handles all `accept()` calls.

per `man systemd.socket`

> A daemon listening on an AF_UNIX socket may,
> but does not need to, call close(2) on the received socket before exiting. However, it must not unlink the socket from a file system.

So a received bound socket must not be `unlink()`ed. On the other hand, even stopping the `.socket` service doesn't remove the inode. To that effect, the `RemoveOnStop=` directive exists.

It would appear the "recommended" way is to let systemd create the socket, pass it to the daemon, and in the daemon at most `close()` it. Once closed, it is of course only closed in the daemon, so the socket is still available in the system. Meaning after a `close()` the service will be again activated.

Presumably a call to `sd_listen_fds()` in a still running service would pass the FD anew. I have not tested this.

TLDR: In a systemd socket activated service, don't  `unlink()`, you may `close()`, `RemoveOnStop=` also deletes the socket file on stop of the .socket service.